# wsdl and xsd's all point to the localhost address on Microsoft SOAP webservices server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I found a webservice on a server and when we try to call it, it doesn't work because the tool we're using to connect to it can't load the dependent XSD files.

This is because everything that loads up from it points to the localhost, so when it tries to load the files on another client, it tries to load them from the client.

I'm uncertain what configures this, I believe that it's from early 2003, some .net program that's running, as I get a screen with a blue bar that says "You have created a service"

Also it has config files that end with `*Service.exe.config` and also `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common`

But everything seems like it's returning the defaults, and nothing seems configured to change the host.

I saw something [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c7fd51a2-773e-41d4-95a0-244e925597fe/wcf-wsdl-generated-paths-for-xsdschema-wsdlimport-soapaddress-wrong-for-wcf-behind-a-firewall?forum=wcf) for a newer version of web services with WCF but I don't really what to change to fix that.

There are other webservices on there that are hosted in IIS, but they don't seem to be these webservices as I don't see a URL listed in IIS for these.

Can anyone identify what library / version of this might be, or how to fix this in the configuration?

Comment: I assume you can download/open the wsdl in a browser? If yes, find all the `<import ... location="">` elements. In location, replace the localhost with the domainname of the server and then download those as well. When you have collected the wsdl and xsd's in a single folder and adapted the wsdl accordingly some tools, like svcutil should be able to process the wsdl based on the files in your local folder.

Comment: @rene Thank you for your help; but I ended up pulling a ‘?singlewsdl’ and it put everything in one wsdl document avoiding the import of the xsd’s.  The client consumer called was then able to use the file locally while pointing at the service machine and it was able to make calls to the service.